# How to use a 3rd dataframe column as x axis ticks/labels in matplotlib scatter

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm struggling to wrap my head around matplotlib with dataframes today. I see lots of solutions but I'm struggling to relate them to my needs. I think I may need to start over. Let's see what you think.

I have a dataframe (ephem) with 4 columns - **Time**, **Date**, **Altitude** & **Azimuth**.

I produce a scatter for **alt** & **az** using:

```
chart = plt.scatter(ephem.Azimuth, ephem.Altitude, marker='x', color='black', s=8)
```

What's the most efficient way to set the values in the **Time** column as the labels/ticks on the x axis?

So:

- the scale/gridlines etc all remain the same
- the chart still plots **alt** and **az**
- the y axis ticks/labels remain as is
- **only the x axis ticks/labels are changed to the Time column.**

Thanks

Comment: In other words, you want to “change the axis-labels using a list of values”. You want to use ax.set_xticklabels(), where ax = plt.gca().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't by any means the cleanest piece of code but the following works for me:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(ephem.Azimuth, ephem.Altitude, marker='x', color='black', s=8)
labels = list(ephem.Time)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
plt.show()
```

Here you will explicitly force the set_xticklabels to the dataframe Time column which you have.

Comment: Never set the ticklabels without setting the tick positions as well!!

Answer (score 0):

In other words, you want to change the x-axis tick labels using a list of values.

```py
labels = ephem.Time.tolist()
# make your plot and before calling plt.show()
# insert the following two lines
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticklabels(labels = labels)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Never set the ticklabels without setting the tick positions as well!!